# Get the google mail ids in phone gap

Tags: android, cordova

---

**Main Activity**

```
//Main Activity Class
//Loading the URL the index.html
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 GoogleAuth cna;

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
        super.init();   

        cna = new GoogleAuth(); 
        appView.addJavascriptInterface(cna, "GoogleAuth");
        appView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

---

**Google Auth**

```
//Google Auth Class
package com.sumeet.daykart;

import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;

public class GoogleAuth extends Activity {
    String email = "";


    @JavascriptInterface
    public String getMailIds() {
        try {
            AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this);
            Account[] accounts = manager.getAccounts();
            for (Account account : accounts) {
                email += account.name + ",";

            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            email = e.getMessage();
        }

        return email;
    }

}
```

---

**Javascript**

```
//JavaScript in index.HTML Page
   var mail =  window.GoogleAuth.getMailIds();
```

---

1. Please can anybody tell me why this code isn't working.
2. I am getting a message saying System Service is not available to activities before                        onCreate()
3. Please let me know the solution..I am badly stuck in this thing.
   Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this. we should pass the reference of the MainActivity to the
     GoogleAuth. so that we can use the reference in the,

```
AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this);
```

The **this** in the `AccountManager` must be the reference of the
     `MainActivity` class.